# StatusStrip label formats my text backwards

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I've been having this problem for a few days. Whenever I update a label in a StatusStrip object it formats my text backwards. I send my label something like

`toolStripVoltage.Text = batteryVoltage.ToString("F2") + " V";`

and the label will display `V 2.82`.

and when I send it something like

`toolStripVoltage.Text = batteryVoltage.ToString("0.00 V");`

it will display the same thing. It seems like no matter how I format the string the "V" goes before the numbers. and! it still puts a space in between the unit and the number. And here's the kicker: when I call this same text to appear in a tooltip of another object like this

`toolStripVoltage.ToolTipText = toolStripVoltage.Text;`

It displays as `2.82 V`. Any ideas on how I can make this work for me?

**EDIT:**

oh wow. I instantly figured this out somehow...the default RightToLeft property is Yes. I don't know why that would be! but the trick was to set that to No. Very strange for that to be the default setting.

Comment: I think it only makes a difference when you are concatenating strings. so `string outputStr="A" + "B";` would show `BA` where as `string outputStr="AB";` would show `AB`. both would right align.

Comment: String concatenation happens before assigning it to the control. RightToLeft seems to reverse the order of words split by whitespace. The default value for the property is that of its parent.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah it looks like the guy that made the statusStrip (parent of the label) set the RtL order to Yes so it would right align in the parent control. there must be a better way to specify alignment within this control than RtL. It doesn't seem like what it is for.

Comment: I see this now. As @C.Evenhuis pointed out my parent control had the default property changed.

Comment: You can accept your own question. This will mark the question as "answered" and it won't show up in list of unanswered questions.